# How do I use the shortcut CTRL+;?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Okay, I've been wondering this for **very** long, but I haven't bothered finding a solution, till now. Okay, my problem is that many applications have shortcuts like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> or similar. Using the semicolon.. Same goes for something like <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.

Both <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> (F#) requires me to use another key to utilise. F# requires me to use **FN+F#**, and <kbd>;</kbd> requires me to use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+.

If I simply try to use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> without <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, nothing happens, and same goes if I use shift.

I imagine the problem is that I'm running a danish keyboard layout, so semicolon is not a separate key, or am I wrong?

Does this even make sense? I hope so.

Comment: What you wrote makes sense.  I just can't tell what your question is.

Comment: Sorry, should have made that more clear.

My question is that I don't know how to use e.g. CTRL+; - without switching keyboard layout - if it's even possible?

Comment: I mean you can use built-in or third-party tools like AutoScript on Windows to create a new shortcut that duplicates those key combinations.  Beyond that if the problem is your keyboard layout conflicts with the keyboard shortcut the simplest solution is use a different keyboard layout.

Comment: Ah okay, yeah I guess - well seems like this is a minor problem not worth wasting time on then. 

Thanks! :-)

Comment: Can't you switch your F#-keys to always on (without the use of FN)? `Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Keyboard.` and `Select the “Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys” checkbox.`. [See here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13982?locale=en_US).